# Contract work – whom should I list on my CV?

Tags: resume

I was recently hired by a university professor as a researcher to work on a contract for a well-known inter-governmental organization. The IGO is paying for this work, but through the university. My direct supervisor is attached to the university, however I am routinely interfacing with the client IGO and I am ultimately answering to their requests. This is a 6-month position. The contract is the only one I am working on, and the one for which I was hired.

From a career perspective, having the name of the IGO front-and-center on my CV would be a huge boost. My question is whether it is justifiable to do so. So something like:

**Researcher - [Inter-governmental organization] - Dates**

- *Contract through [University] providing [Responsibilities]*

Or even something to the effect of:

**Researcher - [University] ([Inter-governmental organization]) - Dates**

- *Contract for [Inter-governmental organization] through [University] providing [Responsibilities]*

Or must I put:

**Researcher - [University] - Dates**

- *Contract for [Inter-governmental organization] providing [Responsibilities]*

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

(For context, I understand short-term work isn't very well viewed, but I'm pretty much fresh out of graduate school so this is something like my first real job.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are employed by the university so you really need to list the university as your employer.  Doing otherwise is incorrect and is also going to create issues for you.  When a prospective employer tries to do a background check, the IGO is going to have no record of you while the university will.

That being said, I think you overestimate the boost that having the "IGO front-and-center" would provide.  A prospective employer reading your resume is going to care about what you did not what entity was cutting the check particularly when you're listing a university that is, presumably, realistically well known (as opposed to a small contracting company that may be completely unknown).  As long as you make that clear, there shouldn't be a penalty for listing the university should be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Your contract is with the University, so the university MUST be listed as the employer; the IGO is the customer. If you happened to work in a fast food chain and served a burger to a celebrity, you don't work for the celebrity - even if that is the only burger you served that day.

As mentioned above, the key things are:

a) You can demonstrate you worked for the IGO in a brief description underneath the job title (or tantalise an interviewer by leaving the description of your role on your CV as 'work undertaken for a major IGO' in the responsibilities: that tends to push interviewers to ask about the work in more detail as they'll be wanting to know who it was).

b) Doing the work for them is one thing - demonstrating completion of the loop is another. Why was the work significant? Was the IGO happy with your work? What did they do with that work - what was its significance? These are selling points given the University was your employer.

Answer (score -2):

> **Disclaimer**
>   You didn't list a location. Some cultures are more formal in regards to a CV. One of the answers mentions that there is a **must** as to who is listed as the employer. But CVs don't have a must-have rulebook in every country/culture. In my experience, a CV is not fact-checked (unless it sounds excessively questionable or the employer works in a high security context) and is more or less used by interviewers as a bullet list to then discuss employment history during an interview.
>   **If your culture does require a strict adherence to CV formalities, you will of course have to defer to those formalities.**

---

I've worked as a consultant for years now. I'm a direct employee of my consulting firm, but I work for clients on-site and hardly interact with my actual employer (other than mailing them a signed timesheet once a month).

I usually list **both** companies. A simple example:

> [Consulting firm]
>   [Role]
>   [Date range]
>
> Consultancy roles as described below.
>
> **Client A**
>   [Date range]
>
> Project A1 description
>
> Project A2 description
>
> **Client B**
>   [Date range]
>
> Project B1 description
>
> Project B2 description

The real employer is important from an administrative point of view. They will be called for references, they might be contacted for HR purposes (e.g. here, some administrative documents in regards to leave and vacation pay are passed from the old employer to the new when an employee changes job).

The client is important to explain your experience. It helps frame your work and responsibilities, and can even highlight similarities/connections with future employers. In my case, I have extensive experience working for several branches of government (as a consultant, so the government is a client), which is a massive foot in the door for future government IT projects.

Comment: @Downvoters: care to elaborate?

Answer (score -4):

Put the IGO if you think it sounds better.

The IGO will kow who you are - you are interfacing with them, after all. Normally background checks that are thorough ask you to fill in all the details again of your CV.

While this can be a titanic waste of time, it does also let you clarify who to check with regarding different positions. In this way you can specify who to check with on the background check, but gain the exposure of the contract work on your CV. The latter case will often help you leap past whatever HR screening you might encounter.

I would then have:

**Inter-governmental organization - Dates**

*Researcher in some field**

- the things you did, with metrics (improved x by y%)
- on top of the day-to-day tasks that the job entailed

The metrics is important to show *how good* you were at the work. Generally, giving a CV with a bulleted list of "tasks" reads no better than a job posting. Make your CV impressive by listing what you accomplished, and using numbers underlines this.